# R get the means for all columns in a data frame while ignoring zeroes

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with columns of simulation data.
I want the means of each column. 
The issue is some columns have a bunch of zeroes on the bottom and these need to be ignored.

I can ignore the zeroes and look at one column with

```
mean(which(df$colname >0))
```

But I want a vector of every column's mean, gotten with sapply.
Is there a clean way to ignore the zeroes and get these values within a sapply function?

Or do I have to write a custom function and call that in the sapply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
sapply(df, function(x) mean(x[x != 0], na.rm = TRUE))
```

Or using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% summarise_all(~mean(.[. != 0], na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

A better/efficient approach would be to set all 0 values to `NA` and use `colMeans`

```
df[df == 0] <- NA
colMeans(df, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use an one-liner in `base R`

```
colMeans(replace(df, !df, NA), na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   summarise(across(everything(), ~ mean(na_if(., 0), na.rm = TRUE))
```